# How to use “Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators” to get Esim Class object

Tags: c#, uwp

There is an `ESim` class in `Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators` in Windows UWP API, I need to get the `ESim` object, but I don't know how to get it. Microsoft has not given an example.

ESim api description:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.esim

Comment: Did you see the note in the documentation you linked that says: _"This functionality is available only to mobile operator apps and UWP apps given privileged access by mobile network operators."_ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a restricted API, that is only available to network operators. It's stated so in the documentation:

> This functionality is available only to mobile operator apps and UWP
>   apps given privileged access by mobile network operators.
>
> If you want to use this API and publish your app to the Microsoft
>   Store, then you'll need to request special approval to use the custom
>   capability **Microsoft.eSIMManagement_8wekyb3d8bbwe**. For more info, see
>   [Custom capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#custom-capabilities).

If you do have access to the privileged API space, you should use the [`GetProfiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.esim.getprofiles#Windows_Networking_NetworkOperators_ESim_GetProfiles) call to get the profile information.